# how to change docusign save signature and instance for docusign developer api

Tags: docusignapi, signature, e-signature

DocuSign is working well but when I open URL and every time available same signature how can I remove or change adopt signature using dousing developer api

Comment: Can you share the code you use? it's not clear what you are doing

Comment: [Try to Solve The Problem First](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) -- 
[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) -- [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)  --  [I Downvoted Because](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/)

Answer (score 0):

**If you're using remote signing:**

Signatures will be saved on the recipient's account. As the recipient, you can log in and delete signatures in the Manage Profile section. https://support.docusign.com/s/articles/How-do-I-change-my-signature-or-adopt-a-custom-signature-NDSE

**If you're using embedded/captive signing:**

Signatures will be saved on a captive recipient profile, tied to the name/email/clientUserId. You can either use a unique ClientUserId to break the association with existing signatures, or you, as the sender, can delete a captive recipient's saved signatures: https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/accounts/accounts/deletecaptiverecipient/

**If you would like your recipients to draw a new signature every time, regardless of using Embedded or Remote signing:**

You can use Sign In Each Location to require recipients to draw a new signature for each signature tab: https://www.docusign.com/blog/developers/common-api-tasks-sign-each-location

If this doesn't address your question, please edit your post to clarify what exactly is happening in your workflow.

Comment: Directing a user to documentation is not an answer, it's a comment..   An answer should *solve* the problem, not invoke more research, which the OP clearly hasn't done themselves.

Comment: Do we have any options on ui to change signature of embedded/captive user